# Почему не работает программа? С++

Tags: c++, математика, ряды, прогрессия

Требуется написать программу, которая находит натуральные числа, кратные 3 и 5 в диапазоне меньше 1000,затем выводит сумму этих чисел.Почему у меня не работает цикл?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int j=0;
    int sum=0;

    for (int i = 1000; i > j; j++)
    {
        if (j % 3)
        {
            sum + j;
        }
        if (j % 5)
        {
            sum + j;
        }
    }

    cout << "Вот сумма чисел кратных 3 или 5 в диапазоне меньше 1000"<<sum <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не присваиваете результат вычислений в sum, а также ваше условие не совсем верно, так как в случае, если число кратно 5 и 3, то число просуммируется два раза.

```
 for (int i = 1000; i > j; j++)
{
    if (j % 3 == 0 || j % 5 == 0)
        sum += j;

}
```

Comment: Это неверно - так суммируются все числа, которые не делятся на 3 или 5.

Answer (score 3):

Что- то тут даже в принятом ответе фигня. И проверка начинается с 0, хотя 0 - **не** натуральное число.

Вот что от вас *хотят*:

```
unsigned int trivial(unsigned int N)
{
    unsigned int s = 0;
    for(unsigned int j = 1; j <= N; ++j)
        if (j%3 == 0 || j%5 == 0) s += j;
    return s;
}
```

А вот куда как более быстрое, а главное - *математическое* решение - просто просуммировать все числа, кратные трем - как арифметическую прогрессию, добавить такую же прогрессию для 5, и вычесть - для 15, чтоб учесть числа, кратные и 3, и 5 одновременно:

```
unsigned int sum_k(unsigned int n) { return n*(n+1)/2; }
unsigned int sum35(unsigned int N) { return 3*sum_k(N/3)+5*sum_k(N/5)-15*sum_k(N/15); }
```

Можете убедиться самостоятельно, что результат одинаков.

Comment: В условии - кратные 3 **и** 5, то есть кратные 15. Так что вы не правы (я понимаю, что судя по коду имелось ввиду **или**, но формально - надо просто `N = 1000; cout << 15*(N/15)*(N/15+1)/2;`).

Comment: @Mikhailo, правильный ответ должен быть 233168. Это задача с [ProjectEuler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1). Так что Harry прав.

Answer (score -1):

Если вы даже исправите на `sum += j`, то ваша программа всеравно будет работать неправильно, так как значение `j` не меняется и, если число кратен и `3` и `5`, то вы просуммируете его два раза. Поэтому нужно:

```
for (int i = 3; i <= 1000; ++i)    
    if (i % 3 || j % 5)        
        sum += i;
```

P.S. Этот код можно и оптимизировать, но к вопросу не касается...